# Why are so many old question suddenly getting new low-quality answers?

Tags: discussion

For the last few weeks I've logged in to this community and seen time and time again a lot of already answered old questions in the front page that got a new unnecessary low-quality response. Are mods thinking of any plans to take measures?

Comment: I have now protected one of [the](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/32163/example-of-a-karpov-vs-kasparov-game-with-a-controversial-move) many such questions. The only help I see right now is to go  through some of the old, highly upvoted questions and protect then.

Comment: @RewanDemontay that's not an old question, it's a HNQ which tends to attract bad answers sometimes. But note that protecting them prevents [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/32231/7297); while not great (yet), it offers a unique example we'd otherwise miss.

Comment: Hi. Interesting problem. Even if a question already has an accepted answer, it can still get a useful answer sometime in the future. Perhaps we can protect all questions with accepted answers and if someone has something useful to contribute as a new answer, they can start by adding a comment to the question?